# Images crawling and indexing Algorithm (by image's color) and text search gives corresponding images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, lucene, indexing, inverted-index

I have a Search Engine, that searches the text and written the corresponding set of web pages by seeing the searched text in inverted index, and throws corresponding webpages.

Now I want to add one more feature, that is, it will search according to the color.

For Example, when I search "**RED SHOES**", it shows me all red shoes that is in inverted index Data structure.

What I thought about the algorithm for the same,

1. Make data structure of images in different place.
2. Whenever find image, just like image of jacket, so calculate all its color by using some color finding algorithm.
3. Put that image in all that color index.

So this is my approach for crawling, when any search just like "red shoes" comes. It finds corresponding red color items by seeing in red index.

This is my algorithm building phase, that's why I didn't write any code for above algorithm. Once I got correct approach then I start my coding phase.

So please give me a suggestion,

Is it a good algorithm? or

Is there any optimization or  changes required, If so , kindly share / discuss that changes with me.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

For any scalable search engine, you are almost certainly better off without image analysis.  Instead, consider indexing images by the text of the attributes in the e.g. `<img>` tag.  For example, if the alt text for an image is `"red shoes"`, then you can index the image under that text. When you later search for `"red"`, the image will have a chance of being returned.

If you are *serious* about doing this kind of image analysis, you could use a library such as image magic to calculate a color histogram.  You could then apply a clustering model or even just a decision tree to notice large amounts of color within certain ranges, and declare a set of color tags (like `"red"`, `"rouge"`, `"vermillion"`, etc) that the image is then indexed under.

If you were feeling absolutely *crazy* you could do cosine similarity on the histograms themselves.  That would let you submit images as *queries*.  Somehow I don't think that's what you have in mind, though.

Comment: Ohk, I understand what you are saying, but suppose I have a lots of jackets, blazzers, etc which have different colors in a single item, then in that case, what can I do?

Comment: I think second paragraph is relevant to me. I think, I have to  use image magic to get the color weightage list in that item once for all images.
If I indexed the image in inverted index. Then during searching as a text query, there may be a chance to return that image. Am I right ?
otherwise improve me please.

Comment: The solution in the second paragraph relies on being able to translate a color histogram into a set of color words.  A typical inverted index (i.e. lucene) is not going to do that for you, you would have to build it from other parts.  Once you have the set of color words for the image, you index the image under those words as in the first paragraph.

Comment: ohk, I will try to implement above instructions. Is this algorithm is optimized one ?

Comment: I want to add some features in luecene, just for learning. So for that Can you give me some good link for luecene, that helps me to understand whole workflow. Can you give me the class diagram of luecene ? Can you give me the workflow of luecene, so that I can able to add some features in that ? Can you give the material so that I can understand which classes do which functionality? If you can and I expect positive reply from your side.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give me reply of my last comment, I am waiting for your reply from long time.

Comment: I don't have any lucene resources off-hand, but I imagine google will be helpful.